From start to finish but only once!
Based on the following...
0 → -
1 → ❌✅✅
2 → ✅❌✅
3 → ✅❌✅
4 → ? ? ? ? ?
5 → ❌✅❌✅
6 → ✅✅
7 → ✅❌✅
8 → ✅
9 → ✅✅

...replace each question mark with the correct symbol.
Hint 1:

 Visual


Based on Mike's and Fitchivalry's answer and the comments under.I think answer is

 ❌❌❌✅✅

because

 From this point (starting point or turning point), is it possible to draw the entire digit in one stroke, from top to bottom, from left to right? If yes, mark with ✅, if no, mark with ❌. 

The completion:

 


Using this logic, I would expect the pattern for 1 to be the same as that for 2, 3 and 7. Why does 1 have the X first?

because you should read the point from top to bottom, from left to right.You can read the completion image!

I like this answer. But my idea was to (which I didnt included in the title) rot13(ivfvg rnpu cbvag bapr, juvpu jvyy lvryq n qvssrerag bhgpbzr ba "4".

I'm giving you the tick anyways, because it's very well fitting and close enough too, just not he idea I had in mind...

Based on Mike's answer and the comments under. I think the answer is

 ❌❌❌✅✅

Because

 If we look at the points in the number and read them top to bottom, left to right, we have ❌ when it is a join point and ✅ when it's an end.

There is something I wonder about the 1 though.

 With the font used in the question, the 1 has a "foot", so the example may need to be ❌✅✅❌✅ in that case.


Now it's getting close, however not the intended solution. You got the right idea (from top to bottom, left to right). Try to involve the hint in the title somehow... Also I chose the two symbols (❌ and ✅) for a reason.

For the record, I see two different fonts on laptop and mobile. The mobile one doesn't contain a foot.

I may be way off but I think it is.

 4 → ❌✅❌✅✅

Because:

 If you look at the way each of the numbers are formed. ✅ are line or curves. where ❌ are a intersection with a point. I am not certain they all work. But five for instace, start with a downstroke to a point ❌. Then there is a curve. ✅ then there is the intersection, ❌ and then you finnish with a line ✅. or 3 is a curve ✅, then in comes to a point ❌ then there is another curve ✅ I am not certain how number like 6,8,9 work with no point and how you know there is two. Also 0 is a - because there is a dot in the middle. (Note i use the font in the image for forming letters. Inter section appear not to be crosses. (See the one)

So for the four:

 There is a point and then a then all the other intersection are sraight lines and in the five starting a new stroke from a point is and ❌ so the four is. a point ❌, then a straigh line ✅, then a line from a point ❌, then an intercesion (not a point see the one) ✅ and then ane finnishing line. ✅ (the last tick may go at then start instead thought.

Also:

 The title also is similar to this method.


You're on the right track that it has something to do with the numbers themselves but not the intended approach

rot13(qba'g sbphf ba yvarf naq pheirf). No distinction between the two. Try to look for other ways the ❌ and ✅ can be mapped to the numbers.

Don't want to say too much but one of your assumptions is correct (ABG yvarf naq pheirf)

I think that rot13(gur ahzore bs "xvaxf" va n ahzore vf rdhny gb gur ahzore bs ❌)
